# Convert pcap to bag file

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear everyone,

I got som trouble when trying to convert a *.pcap file into a *.bag file.

I try the method explained here :
https://answers.ros.org/question/213080/convert-raw-velodyne-vlp16-pcap-to-bagfile/

In a first terminal I launch :
`roscore`

Then in second one, I launch : 
`rosrun rosbag record -o your_vlp16_070815.bag /velodyne_packets` to open the recording file ?

and finally in the third one, I launch :
`rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=bureau.pcap _read_once:=true` to play the pcap file.

I wait until the third command finish ("done" message), then CTRL+C the second command. I got a .*bag file.
After this, I try to view it using RVIZ following this method :
https://answers.ros.org/question/227205/how-to-display-bag-file-in-rviz/

`rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne`
`rosrun velodyne_pointcloud cloud_node`
`rosbag play your_vlp16_070815.bag`

I work with ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

Questions :

- I don't have calibration file (*.yaml) because I get no file from VLP16 distributor. Can you provide me a sample file even if it doesn't correspond to my sensor ?
- When I run the viewer, I get "No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [velodyne] does not exist". I get no points on the screen. Any idea ?

Best regards, Boris Leroux

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268403/convert-pcap-to-bag-file/) by [BorisLerouxFox](https://answers.ros.org/users/31510/borislerouxfox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sohel](https://answers.ros.org/users/32541/sohel/) on 2017-11-08**:
how much time does the third terminal require to finish. Its already more than a hour

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-08**:
That will depend on the size of the `pcap` file. Are you not seeing the `done` message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- When I run the viewer, I get "No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [velodyne] does not exist". I get no points on the screen. Any idea ?

  - You can try rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link velodyne 10. This worked for me. If you have extrinsic data you may input those here. Furthermore select velodyne as fixed frame in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [SoVa](https://answers.ros.org/users/34644/sova/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0